# Can you make an instance of a class not for a type but for a whole class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints

Suppose I want to make all numbers an instance of `Monoid`. Instead of having to create an instance for each `Num` like this:

```
instance Monoid Int where
  mappend = (+)
  mempty = 0

instance Monoid Float where
  mappend = (+)
  mempty = 0.0

-- etc
```

Is there something like this?

```
instance Num t => Monoid t where
  mappend = (+)
  mempty = 0
```

## Edit

Some are answering with GHC extensions and warning about the potential issues; I found that informative, but I think I will stick with `Sum`, `Product` and whatever [`coerce`](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Coercible) does.

Comment: what you are looking for is already there - but there are more than one possible Monoids for numbers - that's why it's there for `Sum` and `Product`([see Data.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid))

Comment: @Carsten So now that I know about `Sum`, I can do this: `mconcat ([1,2] :: Sum Int)`, which is nice, but I can't do `mconcat ([1,2] :: Sum Float)`, nor `mconcat ([1,2] :: Sum Fractional)`. What is the proper way to use `Sum` for `Float`s and `Double`s?

Comment: I have no clue how you got the first to work - but `mconcat ([1,2] :: [Sum Float])` works fine for me ;)

Comment: btw: `Fractional` is no type, it's a class, so `Sum Fractional` makes no sense here (`Sum` wants something of kind `*` as it's first parameter, but `Fractional` is `* -> Constraint`)

Comment: Oops, yes I meant `:: [Sum Int]` in the first example not `:: Sum Int`. And what I couldn't get to work was `mconcat ([1.0, 2.0] :: [Sum Float])`; `mconcat ([1, 2] :: [Sum Float])` works fine.

Comment: the first one will not work because `1.0` is `Fractional something` and I think there is no such instance for `Sum` (there is one for `Num a => Num (Sum a)` so the example with `[1,2]` has no issue at all)

Comment: of course `mconcat [Sum 1.0, Sum 2.0]` will work ;)

Comment: I got significantly less noob today, thanks. I'll check with more detail the source code.

Comment: The Haskell libraries committee recently decided to add another new bunch of instances to `Sum` etc., but they weren't numerical classes. Maybe next time...

Comment: If one of the answers satisfies you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm interpreting this as asking about a general premise, rather than specifically about `Monoid` and `Num`.

Maybe you could get what you wrote to work, by enabling language extensions FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, and using overlapping instances.

But you probably wouldn't want to: it *seems like* `instance Num t => Monoid t where ...` is saying

"If `t` is an instance of `Num`, here's how to make `t` an instance of `Monoid`..."

Unfortunately, that's not right. What it's actually saying is more like

"Here's how to make `t` an instance of `Monoid.` First, it's necessary that `t` be an instance of `Num`. Next..."

Thus, if you write an instance declaration like this, you can't write any other instance declarations. (At least not without `OverlappingInstances`, which would bring its own issues.)

Answer (score 6):

GHC allows your definition with some language extensions enabled

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

instance Num t => Monoid t where
  mappend = (+)
  mempty = 0
```

This makes `2 <> 3` result in `5`.

**But** this overlaps with other `Monoid` instances, so trying to evaluate `"Hello" <> "World"` results with an error: `Overlapping instances for Monoid [Char]`

So, I think that the short answer is: no.