# Haskell Type Class Implied

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to be able to say that for all Types that are an A they are also a B

```
class A g where
  f :: g -> Int

class B g where
  h :: g -> Int

instance A g => B g where
    h = f
```

I'm getting the compile error:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `B g' …
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you make an instance of a class not for a type but for a whole class in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769112/can-you-make-an-instance-of-a-class-not-for-a-type-but-for-a-whole-class-in-hask)

Comment: See in particular [Mike Benfield's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32769655/1477667).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You should not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769655/1477667). However, it's perfectly reasonable to write something like

```
class B g => A g where
  f :: g -> Int
```

This produces a useful entailment. With the `DefaultSignatures` extension (which I personally dislike for various reasons), you can even write

```
class B g where
  h :: g -> Int
  default h :: A g => g -> Int
  h = f
```